# caret train method not working (something is wrong for all accuracy results) for outcomes with >2 categories

Tags: r, r-caret

Hi I know someone asked similar issues before but no clear answer yet (or I tried their solution without success: [Caret error using GBM, but not without caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802216/caret-error-using-gbm-but-not-without-caret)
[Caret train method complains Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685757/caret-train-method-complains-something-is-wrong-all-the-rmse-metric-values-are)
)

I tried to use caret training methods to predict the categorical outcomes (online data examples below)

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
str(Sonar[, 1:10])

library(caret)
set.seed(998)

Sonar$rand<-rnorm(nrow(Sonar))  ##to randomly create the new 3-category outcome
table(Sonar$rand)
Sonar$Class_new<-ifelse(Sonar$Class=="R","R",ifelse(Sonar$rand>0,"M","H"))
table(Sonar$Class_new)

fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
                           method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           ## repeated ten times
                           repeats = 10)

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class_new, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

gbmFit1 <- train(Class_new ~ ., data = training,
                 method = "gbm",
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

Whenever I used the new class variable (`Class_new`) which has 3 categories, rather than 2 categories in original `Class` variable, I got the warnings below. It runs fine with 2 category outcome variables. And it is the same case regardless of the train methods (I tried `rf`, `gbm`, svm, all the same)

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

```
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :9     NA's   :9
```

> Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
>         The metric "RMSE" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.
>       2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
>         There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you reference that you are building on prior questions, ie-"someone tried this before", you should provide a link to those questions in your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caret and KNN in R: predict function gives error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200033/caret-and-knn-in-r-predict-function-gives-error)

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [getting this error in Caret](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475723/getting-this-error-in-caret)

Comment: I edited and put those prior threads links that did not work me..

Comment: Still none of the previous threads helped, including the above 2 posts from Alex and phiver..but thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the newly created `Class_new` to a factor, as follows:

```
Sonar$Class_new<-ifelse(Sonar$Class=="R","R",ifelse(Sonar$rand>0,"M","H"))
Sonar$Class_new <- factor(Sonar$Class_new)
```

Also, you may want to remove the variables `Class` and `rand` from your training and testing data sets. You can do somthing like:

```
training <- Sonar[ inTraining, !(names(Sonar) %in% c("Class", "rand"))]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining, !(names(Sonar) %in% c("Class", "rand"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had allowParallel = TRUE in the train function and the machine I was working on did not have multiple cores. After I commented that statement, I did not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the formula in the  train function, pass values for parameters x, y, method etc

the old way:

```
modFit = train(data.df$Label ~ ., 
                 data = data.df, 
                method = "rpart", 
                trControl= cntr, 
                tuneLength = 7)
```

new way:

```
modFit = train(x = data.df.cols, 
                 y = data.df$Label,
                 method = "rpart",
                   trControl = cntrl, 
                   tuneLength = 7)
```

Note: x = data.df.cols has all columns except the label, data.df.cols = data.df[,2:ncol(data.df)]

Answer (score 0):

Thank howaj for your post. That did work for the data I posted but somehow did not work for another dataset, where everything seems to be the same. But I figured out finally:

Could be a syntax issue here. Instead of using train(y~., data=training, ...), I changed to the train(train$y,train$x, ...) without specifying data=.. explicitly:

```
train(training[,!names(training)%in%response], training$response ...)
```

This worked.

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I know, some packages accept only one form (formula interface or x and y interface, but not both).

Comment: I also found that syntax mattered depending on which `method` was used in `train()`.